# Back up on Redhat

Tags: linux, backup

Before installing Autodesk I have to back up all the files, videos, pictures etc.

I don't have any idea how to do.

Is there anybody who has an idea for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following static method has the benefit of being simple to it. If you are looking into automatic set-it-and-forget-it backup solutions, this is not the post where you will find what you need.

Create a directory under your home directory called backup or whatever name you want to choose and copy in all files you want to backup:

```
$ mkdir -p '~/backup/videos'
$ mkdir -p '~/backup/pics/'
$ mkdir -p '~/backup/files/'
$ cp -a '/path/to/yourvideos/*' '~/backup/videos/'
$ cp -a '/path/to/yourpics/*' '~/backup/pics/'  
$ cp -a '/path/to/files/*' '~/backup/files/'
```

Now archive and compress the directory:

```
$ cd ~
$ tar -czvf backup.tar.gz backup
```

This should save all of your files to `backup.tar.gz`. The only thing you have to do now is copy the archive somewhere else.

```
$ cp ~/backup.tar.gz /path/to/someplace
```

Answer (score 0):

using the cp (copy) command.

e.g.:

```
cp -r /home/user/* /backuplocation
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be backing up the whole time (not just when installing new software). You can find a cheap/free service for backing up user files here:

http://skeptu.com/linux-online-backup

Some services will auto-discover your photos, documents, etc. and you can back everything up just by clicking through the set up wizard.